# RemoveEventListener JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как правильно удалить такого слушателя или как его можно задать по-другому?

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", () => { setTimeout(checkUp, 100) });

вот так не работает :

canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", () => { setTimeout(checkUp, 100) });

Заранее благодарна за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо передавать в таком случае не анонимную функцию. Т.е. вначале создать именованную, например `let test = () => { ... };` А затем передавать ссылку на неё:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", test);
canvas.removeEventListener("mouseup", test);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: Вот так можно передать, если нужны аргументы. `const getResult = (a, b) => {
  console.log(a, b);
};
const clickGetResult = () => getResult(1, 2);`